# Exception after Umbraco upgrade 7.5.11

Tags: c#, razor, umbraco7

After running the 7.5.11 upgrade on our Umbraco web site I am getting an exception in one of my Partial View Macro Files (cshtml):

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentExtensions.GetPropertyValue(IPublishedContent content, String alias)
```

The exception is pointing to this line:

```
var mediaItem = Umbraco.TypedMedia(item.GetPropertyValue("propAliasString"));
```

The line is in this foreach loop:

```
@foreach (var item in news.Where(x => x.GetPropertyValue<int>("group") == year.Key).OrderByDescending(y => y.GetPropertyValue("date")))
    {
        var mediaItem = Umbraco.TypedMedia(item.GetPropertyValue("announcement"));

            <div class="panel-body">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;<a href="@mediaItem.GetPropertyValue("umbracoFile")" target="_blank">@item.GetPropertyValue("headline")</a>
                <p style="margin-left:16px;" class="date">@( Convert.ToDateTime(item.GetPropertyValue<string>("date")).Date.ToString("d. MMMMM yyyy"))</p>
            </div>
    }
```

I have tried to browse the Umbraco documentation for changes in the api from 7.4 to 7.5 regarding this issue.

Before the upgrade this worked.

Has any of you experienced this kind of error? - and more important found a solution?

best regards
Jesper

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution - kind of embarrasing.

A check on the property for null value is needed:

```
var mediaItem = Umbraco.TypedMedia(item.GetPropertyValue(".."));
if(mediaItem != null)
{
 ....
}
```

Anyways my excuse is that it worked before the upgrade. :-)

/Jesper

Comment: You should also purge the website cache by going to /Umbraco/dialogs/republish.aspx?xml=true